# MKMapView Why 'setRegion' will block main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.location.coordinate, 100, 100);
}
```

When I set the region at the first time, the main thread will be blocked.

Comment: first remove the line and add debugPrint("updatedUserLocation") and check if is called so many times but this code is the same as I use in several projects and it works just fine

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: I think that your main thread is blocked by another issue, you can check that removing the line and testing if still is blocked your main thread

Comment: any updates on this?